# Inconsistency reading from serial port in C LINUX

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, termios

I have an inconsistency problem while I read in my serial port using Linux and C.

The code that I use to configure the serial port is this:

```
serial = open("/dev/ttymxc1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);      //Open in non blocking read/write mode
    if (serial == -1)
    {
        //ERROR - CAN'T OPEN SERIAL PORT
        printf("Error - Unable to open UART.  Ensure it is not in use by another application\n");
    }

    struct termios tty;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if (tcgetattr (serial, &tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("error from tcgetattr");
        return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed (&tty, B115200);

    tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
    // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
    // as \000 chars
    //tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // disable break processing
    tty.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                                            // no canonical processing
    tty.c_oflag = 0;                // no remapping, no delays
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;            // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);// ignore modem controls,
                                            // enable reading
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
    tty.c_cflag |= 0;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

    if (tcsetattr (serial, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("error from tcsetattr");
        return -1;
    }
```

Then I poll the UART (from the same thread which has configured the serial port) with the following code:

```
while(1)
{
    if (serial != -1)
    {
        //memset(rx, 0, sizeof(rx));
        int rx_length = read(serial, &rx, MAX_TXRX_BUF);        //Filestream, buffer to store in, number of bytes to read (max)
        if(rx_length > 0){
            //Bytes received
            //rx[rx_length] = '\0';

            printf("1) %i bytes read : %s\n", rx_length, rx);
            //forward_data(rx, rx_length);
            printf("2) %i bytes read : %s\n", rx_length, rx);
            //tcflush(serial, TCIOFLUSH);
        }
        // else: NO DATA
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr, "TEST: %s SERIAL FAIL\n", __func__);
        releaseUart();
    }

}
```

The problem is that this print:

```
printf("1) %i bytes read : %s\n", rx_length, rx);
```

always WORKS and print the correct data read from serial.
While the second print:

```
printf("2) %i bytes read : %s\n", rx_length, rx);
```

which is immediately below the first one, sometimes works and other items it just prints an unknown character.

Below I show you the ouput but in the case in which it works and in the case in which it does not work:

Correct:

```
1) 2 bytes read : gv
2) 2 bytes read gv
```

Wrong:

```
1) 2 bytes read : gv
2) 2 bytes read: �
```

Why even if the two prints are one below the other sometimes I get these kind of inconsistencies in printing the SAME buffer?

Thanks in advance very much for your help.

Best regards,
Marco

Comment: After applying zwol's fixes, you may be trying to output _binary_ that is outside the ASCII range. It _may_ try to interpret it as utf-8 and get confused. That diamond question mark symbol is an indicator of that. Try: `void prt(unsigned char *buf,int len) { unsigned int chr;  for (;  len > 0;  --len, ++buf) { chr = *buf; if ((chr >= 0x20) && (chr <= 0x7E)) printf("%c",(char) chr); else printf("{?%2.2X?}",chr); } }`

Comment: What do you have rx declared as?  Is it a char or word or long?

Comment: *"Below I show you the ouput ..."* -- Your output looks bogus.  In the "correct" output, why does the second line have no colon?  In the "wrong" output, where did the *"SERIAL READ:"* come from instead of *"bytes read :"* that's in the **printf()**?

Comment: Hello @sawdust I simply made a mistake copying it, I have corrected the question with the same output.

Comment: Hello @Baddack it is declared as char rx[MAX_TXRX_BUF];

Comment: Hello @CraigEstey I found that the frong character is a NULL, your function prints: {?00?}

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain why the output changes between the first `printf` and the second.  However, `read` does not NUL-terminate its buffer, which means, after you do

```
int rx_length = read(serial, &rx, MAX_TXRX_BUF);
```

you do *not* have a valid C string in `rx`.  You need to do something like this instead:

```
char rx[MAX_TXRX_BUF + 1]; // extra space for terminator
ssize_t rx_length = read(serial, rx, MAX_TXRX_BUF);
if (rx_length >= 0) {
    rx[rx_length] = '\0';
    // use rx here
    // if rx_length == 0, handle EOF
} else {
    // read error
}
```

Even though I don't know why the output changes, I predict that if you put your two `printf` statements where I have `// use rx here`, they will always print the same thing.

N.B. taking the address of an entire array, as you did with `&rx`, is almost always a mistake.  In most cases what you actually want, in order to refer to an array in C, is the address of the first element, which is what you get with just `rx`.  (For reasons too tedious and tangential to get into here, `read` doesn't care which one of the two you supply it, but in other cases it can lead to subtle bugs.  Therefore, best practice in C is to use the address of the first element even in cases where it doesn't matter; reserve `&rx` for the rare cases where you do specifically need the address of the entire array.)

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply and suggestions. I have added your changes, but even if I put the two printf inside where you told me sometimes the ouput of the second is corrupted as I shown above. I do not know why, it is very strange. rx is definied as unsigned char rx[MAX_TXRX_BUF];

Comment: (1) Did you change rx to `unsigned char rx[MAX_TXRX_BUF + 1]` also? (2) Run your program under `valgrind`, does it report any errors? If so, fix them; did that make the problem go away?

Comment: Hello @zwol and thank you for your hints. I have also changed rx to unsigned char rx[MAX_TXRX_BUF + 1] but the same problem happens. I will check with valgrind to see if it reports any errors. At the moment I have not solved it. I am also following some suggestions from other users for example by printing the wrong character when it appears. I found by printing the wrong character that it is a NULL. If I find other helpful informations I will post them here. Thank you for your time.